# SQLAlchemy returning strings instead of datetime objects

Tags: python, database, datetime, sqlalchemy, freetds

I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to a SQL Server database. The table I'm querying has a `DATETIME` column. On Windows, the resulting attribute on the SQLAlchemy object is a Python `datetime` object. On Linux, it's a string.

My SQLAlchemy class looks like this

```
class MyTable(Model):
    id_ = db.Column('Id', db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    as_of_date = db.Column('AsOfDate', db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=db.FetchedValue())
    # Other columns
```

On Windows, I get this

```
>>db.session.query(MyTable.as_of_date).first()
datetime.datetime(2006, 11, 30, 0, 0)
```

On Linux, I get this

```
>>db.session.query(MyTable.as_of_date).first()
('2006-11-30 00:00:00.00000000',)
```

My connection strings look like this

```
Linux
mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER={FreeTDS};Server=my_server;Port=1433;Database=my_database;UID=my_user;PWD=my_password;TDS_Version=8.0;

Windows
mssql+pyodbc://my_user:my_password@my_server/my_database?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the FreeTDS driver. Although, SQLAlchemy [documentation states](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html) that

> DATE and TIME are supported. Bind parameters are converted to
>   datetime.datetime() objects as required by most MSSQL drivers, and
>   **results are processed from strings if needed**. The DATE and TIME types
>   are not available for MSSQL 2005 and previous - if a server version
>   below 2008 is detected, DDL for these types will be issued as
>   DATETIME.

How can I fix this so that the Linux calls return `datetime` objects?

Comment: Is it important to use `mssql+pyodbc` and not `mssql+pymssql`? Maybe it's an ODBC issue. I get normal `datetime` objects using it, based on the same FreeTDS.

Comment: @9000 I changed my connection string to `mssql+pymssql://my_user:my_password@my_server/my_database` and I still get the same result as above.

Comment: Is your Linux box running reasonably current versions of FreeTDS and SQLAlchemy?

Comment: I think so? `tsql -C | grep Version` prints `Version: freetds v0.91` and `pip freeze | grep ^SQLAlchemy` prints `SQLAlchemy==1.1.5`. Not sure if those are the pertinent version numbers.

Comment: @KrisHarper - What does `SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTable' AND COLUMN_NAME='AsOfDate'` say? (Also remember to "@ping" your replies to notify the other party.)

Comment: @GordThompson Aha. It is actually a `DATETIME2` column. According to [this link](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/faq.html#pymssql-does-not-unserialize-date-and-time-columns-to-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-instances) I will need to upgrade to FreeTDS 0.95 in order for it to deserialize it correctly. Now to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that the column was actually DATETIME2 (not DATETIME) and the Linux box had FreeTDS 0.91 installed. In order for FreeTDS to fully support DATETIME2 columns you need to be running FreeTDS 0.95 or newer and using TDS protocol version 7.3 or 7.4.

(Note that TDS_Version "8.0" is really just an alias for version 7.1, so it is *not* newer than 7.3. Ref: [here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm).)

Of course, your other option is to switch from FreeTDS_ODBC to the [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-linux). That, combined with pyodbc, is a configuration that is officially supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about TDS version 8.0. I would have been stuck on that for a while.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, using `mssql+pymssql`, I got this working after executing `sudo apt install freetds-bin`.
`tsql -C | grep Version` returns freetds v1.00.82 at the time of this post.